# Xamarin Copy File Cross Platform

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

Is it possible to copy a file in Xamarin Cross Platform? e.g. copy a SQLlite db3 from one directory to another. All i can get is the path of the file.

I found solutions for Xamarain.Android and iOS but I want to have it combined in one Portable class.

**EDIT**
Maybe there are better solutions out there but here is what I got with PCL Sotrage.

```
        IFile file = FileSystem.Current.GetFileFromPathAsync(src).Result;
        IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(dest).Result;
        IFolder folder = rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists).Result;
        IFile newFile = folder.CreateFileAsync("TodoItem.db3", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName).Result;

        Stream str = file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite).Result;
        Stream newStr = newFile.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite).Result;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[str.Length];
        int n;
        while ((n = str.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            newStr.Write(buffer, 0, n);
        str.Dispose();
        newStr.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid having to deal with different filesystems and their quirks on each platform, you can use the PCLStorage library to do quite a wide array of operations on all Xamarin.Forms platforms.

Take a look at it here: https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage

Answer (score 5):

I think a good solution is to use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/).

For Example, in PCL create an Interface

```
public interface IFile {
    void Copy ( string fromFile, string toFile );
}
```

In Android the platform-specific implementation

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (FileImplementation))]
namespace File.Droid {
  public class FileImplementation : IFile
  {
      public FileImplementation() {}

      public void Copy(string fromFile, string toFile)
      {
            System.IO.File.Copy(fromFile, toFile);
      }

  }
}
```

Then in your PCL you can call

```
DependencyService.Get<IFile>().Copy("myfile", "newfile");
```

With .NETStandard you could use System.IO directly in your PCL Project

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i want to have the logic in the shared code.

Answer (score 1):

The cool new way to do it would be to use a .Net Standard library instead of a PCL.  .Net Standard 1.6 is supported on Xamarin.IOS and Xamarin.Android and include System.IO.File unlike PCL profiles.

You could also use a Shared Project instead of a PCL, since both X.IOS and X.Android include System.IO.File support, it would work pretty seamlessly in a Shared Project.

Otherwise, If you are using Xamarin Forms, I think Alessandro's DependencyService solution is a good one, and even if you aren't using Forms, the interface abstraction idea applies.