# Copy all dll files which are built from other projects to assets

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to make the dll files built from other projects to be the assets files in the Xamarin Android project.

For example, I have "A" project and it is a Xamarin Android project.

And I have B and C project, and they will be built and generate dll files.

After B and C finish their building process, I want their dll files to be copied to assets folder of "A" project and make these dll files as android assets.

Have any way to reach this requirement?
Thanks!

Comment: Why?  What purpose would this serve?

Comment: @Jason Because my app is already working on Windows and Linux. In the base code of t my app, it would use `Assembly.LoadFrom("path")` to load other assembly. I want it would have the same behavior on Android if it's possible.

Comment: Could this be help?[Xamarin Copy File Cross Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676408/xamarin-copy-file-cross-platform)

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution.

For B and C project, they should be added post build event like:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xcopy /q /y &quot;$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).dll&quot; &quot;$(SolutionDir)\A\Assets&quot;" />
</Target>
```

And also need to add `<DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>` in `PropertyGroup`

Then after B and C finish their building, their dll files would be copied to assets folder of A.

And in A project, it also should be added post build event and the setting of assets folder.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- I use Avalonia here. Change to AndroidAsset in Maui or Xamarin-->
  <AvaloniaResource Include="Assets\**" />
</ItemGroup>
.
.
.
<Target Name="PostBuild" BeforeTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="del &quot;$(ProjectDir)Assets\*.dll&quot; /q" />
</Target>
```

The post build event will remove dll files after building is done.